# Why i'm getting error on a new class: does not contain a definition for 'Run'?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using google api v3 and i try to use this example the first one that say: Retrieve my uploads. In this example they are using the Run and Wait. I wanted to try it too in this way.
This is the top of the example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
  /// <summary>
  /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: retrieve my uploads.
  /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
  /// See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
  /// </summary>
  internal class MyUploads
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: My Uploads");
      Console.WriteLine("============================");

      try
      {
        new MyUploads().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }
```

And this is my class what i did:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;


namespace Youtube
{


    class Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads
    {
        public Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads()
        {
            try
            {
                new Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

Error   1   'Youtube.Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads' does not contain a definition for 'Run' and no extension method 'Run' accepting a first argument of type 'Youtube.Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, as it says, there is no `Run` method in `Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads`, it seems you are expecting the constructor to return a task of some sort? Even if you could get this to compile, it would throw a stack overflow exception...

Comment: Looks like code sample missing Run methods... If it is indeed full [MCVE] than I see no reason why you expect this code to work - please provide your reasoning why clases you've shown should have `Run` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to implement the Method `public Task Run()` on the class `Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads`. Don't worry: happens to the best of us. Just implement it, and the compiler error will go away :)

Oh and also: the constructor of `Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads` is recursive. So if you start your program it will crash with a stack overflow. You might want to fix that too.

Comment: Abbondanza how do i fix the recursive ? What's the best way

Comment: @SharondohpSharonas Your Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads constructor creates another Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads object, whos constructor will create another Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads object and so on. Don't make a new one of itself in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to instantiate `Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads` but it doesn't contain the `Run` method. Try this example from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet):

```
/*
*/
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
  /// <summary>
  /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: retrieve my uploads.
  /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
  /// See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
  /// </summary>
  internal class MyUploads
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: My Uploads");
      Console.WriteLine("============================");

      try
      {
        new MyUploads().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
      UserCredential credential;
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
            // user's account, but not other types of account access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
      }

      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
      });

      var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
      channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

      // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
      var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
      {
        // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
        // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
        var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

        Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

        var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
          var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
          playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
          playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
          playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

          // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
          var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

          foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
          {
            // Print information about each video.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
          }

          nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, classes will extend from the "object" class. Run() and Wait() are not part of that object() class. Your class, Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads does not have any methods (outside of the constructor) shown, and it doesn't extend any other class.

The sample must only show a snipped of that class, where Run() and Wait() are defined elsewhere.